# How to configure Google Maps Distance Matrix API for Android (java)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I am developing an Android app(java) that can calculate the travel distance of two places given their coordinates. I have a Google Distance Matrix API key with me but I was unable to find a proper way to add the dependency in my Android project. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can use Java client library for web services: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method is to develop a REST API and call Distance Matrix API and transfer the decoded JSON object to app as a String.